# Running apt-get update / upgrade

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I'm still fairly new to Linux / Ubuntu and so here's my basic question.
I have installed mongoDB version 2.6.5 on a 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04 box.  From time to time, I get prompted about my system needing updates.
I'm wondering if I say ok to these updates (or run the apt-get update / upgrade commands manually) will it break any of my dependencies?

How can I control / choose what gets updated?

Answer (score 0):

When you are prompted to update, click 'details':

There, you can uncheck the items you don't want to update.